# I have a complex puzzle regarding serialization of data

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

(C# and Unity) I have a game already out on the market being played and I need to update it by adding new content. I have a class with an  list that adds all of my save classes to, serializes it using binaryformatter and, upon load, deserializes it and restores data.

The problem I'm having right now is that I am using an exporting of ToBase64String of the memory stream to allow players to backup their data. This created an unforeseen complication where I can't allow them to reload their data using this method anymore.

I cannot add a new class to the preexisting object list or it wrecks saved data.
I cannot add new variables to preexisting saved classes or it wrecks saved data. (I understand why it's doing this mind you.)
I can serialize both objects using separate memory streams and strings to represent them. However, reloading using the importing of FromBase64String cannot work with this method unless I forced players to put the binary code into different boxes which would confuse them so it's not an option.

What I need to know is if I am overlooking some way to deserialize ONE serialized Base64String that contains two objects get both of these objects after load. The problem is I only see a way to grab the first object that was saved out but not both.

It is too late to change how I am saving and loading data so I need to somehow work with what I already have. Since I am limited to the loveliness of Unity and Monobehavior, C++ isn't an option.

I hope you can understand what I'm asking I tried my best to explain it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't understand. Is the saving and backup two different things? What are the two objects that you serialize? What are you serializing right now and what would you like to serialize instead? And it's never too late to change anything, you could read/write data in multiple formats, by adding a version number to the format and converting old formats to new formats when you save them.

Comment: The two objects are List<object> savedData1 and List<object> savedData2. They are lists that contain several different class objects. I need to add another savedData object list as my serialization currently only has one. The issue is, as you can read above regarding the Base64String and deserialization of that.

Comment: You say you have two lists, and then you say you need to add another but you only have one. Isn't that the 3rd one then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if I understand you correctly, you need to serialize multiple objects into a string. Well that's really easy, you can serialize any number of objects into a memory stream, and also read it back the same way:

```
        var bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, DateTime.Now);
        bf.Serialize(ms, "hello world");
        var str = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

        ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(str));
        var obj1 = (DateTime)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        var obj2 = (string)bf.Deserialize(ms);

        Console.WriteLine(obj1);
        Console.WriteLine(obj2);
```

Anyway, I would like to suggest that you implement some kind of data format versioning. If there's a new format, create new objects for that, and when you release a new version of your app, then you can read back data in the old format and convert it to the new one.

Comment: Not quite. I am serializing two List<object> then, afterwards, converting the memory stream ToBase64String. I need to deserialize two List<object> yet somehow differentiate between the two.

Comment: I don't understand. You read back one list, that's the first, and you read back another, that's the second. You get them back in the same order you wrote them. That's the only way you can differentiate.

Comment: I just tried what you said and it actually worked. I feel like the biggest retard right now. I had no idea it worked like that but now I do, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me realize how dumb I am (but teach me at the same time). You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

In a new version of your program, you could try deserializing the data using both old and new methods, and sniffing the deserialized data to make sense of it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_sniffing